# ASP.NET Web API does not get POST data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have some json object in the client (browser in this case) as follows

```
objeto = {
  idSala: idSala,
  listaEtapas: listaEtapas,
  listaMacros: listaMacros,
  listaTI: listaTI,
  listaTU: listaTU,
  listaUnidades: listaUnidades,
  listaTorres: listaTorres,
  valor: valor,
  regla: regla,
  finicio: finicio,
  ffin: ffin,
  activo: activo
};
$.post("/api/reglas", objeto).done(function() {
  alert("ok");
})
```

As you see I'm sending it thru jquery post method to a IISexpress server on my own developing machine.

In C# I've created the corresponding model:

```
public class reglaInsercion
{
      int idSala { get; set; }
      int[] listaMacros { get; set; }
      int[] listaEtapas { get; set; }
      int[] listaTI { get; set; }
      int[] listaTU { get; set; }
      int[] listaUnidades { get; set; }
      string [] listaTorres { get; set; }
      double valor { get; set; }
      string regla { get; set; }
      DateTime finicio { get; set; }
      DateTime ffin { get; set; }
      bool activo { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have set the respective controller action

```
[Route("api/reglas")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage postRegla(reglaInsercion laRegla)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

But when I debug my code the laRegla object has alll its members to null or zero depending of the data type. What am I missing? I've read the docs and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In Chrome console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: idSala is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your model as follows:

```
public class reglaInsercion
{
    public int idSala { get; set; }
    public int[] listaMacros { get; set; }
    public int[] listaEtapas { get; set; }
    public int[] listaTI { get; set; }
    public int[] listaTU { get; set; }
    public int[] listaUnidades { get; set; }
    public string[] listaTorres { get; set; }
    public double valor { get; set; }
    public string regla { get; set; }
    public DateTime finicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime ffin { get; set; }
    public bool activo { get; set; }
}
```

Adding `public` key to your properties.

Comment: It worked!!! After four hours of trying almost everything. Thanks a lot. I feel very dumb right now

Comment: You're welcome friend, do not forget to accept this answer as a valid response, it may be useful to other users. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you need the following above the methods your calling via AJAX.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[Route("api/reglas")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage postRegla(reglaInsercion laRegla)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```